# Unset doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

Here is some php code:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    //Параметры для соединения с БД
    define('DB_SERVER', '');
    define('DB_USERNAME','');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
    define('DB_DATABASE', '');
    //Подключение класса для соединения к БД
    require_once 'database_class.php';


    //Соединение с БД
    Database::Connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

    $citiesArray = array('Челябинск', 'Миасс');
    $table = "CitiesGraphic";
    $rows = '*';
    $output = '['."<br>";

    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($citiesArray); $i++) { 
        $where = "city = '".$citiesArray[$i]."'";
        Database::setEncoding();
        $selectResult = Database::Select($table, $rows, $where);
        if($i<sizeof($citiesArray)-1){
            $line = '{"city":"'.$selectResult[0][0].'","percentage":"'.$selectResult[0][1].'"},'."<br>";
        }
        else{
            $line = '{"city":"'.$selectResult[0][0].'"percentage":"'.$selectResult[0][1].'"},'."<br>";
        }
        $output .= $line;
        echo $citiesArray[$i].", ";
        unset($selectResult);
    } 
    $output .= ']';

    echo $output;
    // Закрываем соединение с базой данных
    Database::Close();
    ?>
```

Some javascript outputs php's echo. Queries are ok, but selectResult is wrong.

Queries:

```
select * from CitiesGraphic where city = 'Челябинск' 

select * from CitiesGraphic where city = 'Миасс'
```

my SelectResult:

```
[<br>{"city":"Челябинск","percentage":"50.00"},<br>{"city":"Челябинск","percentage":"50.00"}<br>]
```

needed selectresult:

```
[<br>{"city":"Челябинск","percentage":"50.00"},<br>{"city":"Миасс","percentage":"50.00"}<br>]
```

i've checked queries in mysql terminal. They're ok.

Here is database_class.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
//Класс для соединения с ДБ
class Database{
    public static $connectDB;//результат соединения со средой
    public static $selectDB;//результат выбора БД
    public static $numResults;
    public static $res;
    public static $ins;
    public static $del;

      public static function numRows(){
        return self::$numResults;
    }

    //Метод для соединения с БД
    public static function Connect($host, $user, $pass, $name){
        //Попытка соединения с БД
        self::$connectDB = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
        if(!self::$connectDB){
            echo "Подключение к серверу БД не удалось. Ошибка: '".mysql_error()."'";
            exit();
            return false;
        }
        //Выбор нужной БД
        self::$selectDB = mysql_select_db($name, self::$connectDB);
        if(!self::$selectDB){
            echo "Не удалось выбрать требуемую БД. Ошибка: '".mysql_error()."'";
            exit();
            return false;
        }
        //Возвращение результата
        return self::$connectDB;
    }

    //Метод для выбоа данных из таблицы
    public static function Select($tableName, $rows='*', $where = null){
        $q = 'select '.$rows.' from ' .$tableName;
        if ($where != null){
            $q .= ' where '.$where;
        } 
        echo $q.'<br />';
        $query = mysql_query($q);
        $res = array();
        if($query){
            self::$numResults = mysql_num_rows($query);

            for($i=0; $i<self::$numResults; $i++){
            self::$res[]= mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM); 
            }
            //echo "ok";
            return self::$res;
        }
        else{
            echo "Ошибка: '".mysql_error()."'";
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Метод для добавления записи в таблицу
    public static function Insert($tableName, $values, $rows = null){
        $insert = 'insert into '.$tableName;
        if ($rows != null) {
            $insert .= ' ('.$rows.')';
        }
        $insert .= ' values ('.$values.')';
        $ins = mysql_query($insert);
        //echo $insert;
        if($ins){
            //echo "ok";
            return true;
        }
        else{
            echo "Ошибка: '".mysql_error()."'";
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Метод для удаления записи из таблицы
    public static function Delete($tableName, $where = null){
        if($where == null){
            $delete = 'delete '.$tableName;
        }
        else{
            $delete = 'delete from '.$tableName.' where '.$where;
        }
        //echo $delete;
        $del = mysql_query($delete);
        if ($del) {
            echo "ok";
            return true;
        }
        else{
            echo "Ошибка: '".mysql_error()."'";
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Метод для обновления записи в таблице
    public static function Update($tableName, $set, $where = null){
        if($where == null){
            $update = 'update '.$tableName.' set '.$set;
        }
        else{
            $update = 'update '.$tableName.' set '.$set.' where '.$where;
        }
        //echo $update;
        $upd = mysql_query($update);
        if ($upd){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            echo "Ошибка: '".mysql_error()."'";
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Метод для закрытия соединения с БД
    public static function Close(){
        return mysql_close(self::$connectDB);
    }

    //Метод для установки кодировки
    public static function setEncoding(){
        $encoding = 'SET NAMES utf8';
        $enc = mysql_query($encoding);
        if ($enc){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            echo "Ошибка: '".mysql_error()."'";
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What happens if you do `$selectResult=null;` instead?

Comment: Скорее всего ошибка в методе Select `$res = array();`, должно быть `self::$res = array();`. И unset необязателен в цикле.